# @Transaction makes my REST Endpoints disappear

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**tl;dr**

- Have a `@RestController` implementing an Interface
- Everything works fine
- added `@Transactional`
- REST endpoints are not being registered any longer until I completely remove the Interface

**Long story**:

I'm using Spring Boot with Spring MVC to deliver RESTful Webservices. I had a `@RestController` class implementing an Interface which had all the `@RequestMapping` Annotations to have a better overview about what Endpoints are there and mapped to which Controller Methods.

```
@RestController
public class UserController extends AbstractController implements IUserController {
...
}

@RequestMapping("/blub/user/")
public interface IUserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "showEditUser/{id}", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    public ShowEditUserResponse showEditUser(final Long userId);
...
}
```

Everything was working fine. On Startup I got a bunch of log messages like:

`Mapped "{[/blub/user/updateUser],methods=[PUT]}" onto public org.blub.core.rest.model.user.UpdateUserResponse org.blub.server.controller.impl.UserController.updateUser(org.blub.core.rest.model.user.UpdateUserRequest)`

Then I added `@Transactional` to the Implementation of the Controller (also tried the Interface). Now the logmessage changed:

`Mapped "{[/blub/user/updateUser],methods=[PUT]}" onto public org.blub.core.rest.model.user.UpdateUserResponse org.blub.server.controller.IUserController.updateUser(org.blub.core.rest.model.user.UpdateUserRequest)`

Please notice, that the message change frpm `impl.UserController` to `IUserController` which results in a 404 HTTP Status when calling the URI.

When I move all `@RequestMapping` annotations to the Implementation and remove the whole Interface, everything works as expected.

Why is having an Interface causing this kind of trouble? I thought that especially when it comes to AOP based proxying, Interface is a "must have"?!

Comment: Interface is not not a must have. If you don't have an interface Spring will try to use Cglib to create a proxy that extends your class.

Comment: Ok, but it should also work when there is an interface, right? I want it for prettiness ;)

Comment: As far as I remember, RequestMapping annotations are not marked as Inherited and they may get lost with too many proxies being created. As a way around your problem do as follows: create a specialised Service to perform entire DB related logic and put Transactional annotations there. Inject this Service to your Controller and it will work. As for prettyness: it is a matter of taste. I don't like to create unneccessary code (like interfaces). With modern IDEs extraction of an interface - when needed - takes no time at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and my project also use javamelody, whitch is a monitoring library working with proxy.

After disabling it, my rest endpoint went back to life.
So the problem is probably linked with some proxy interference between spring mvc and a proxy library.

Comment: In your case with auto-proxies issues, it is suggested to add
    advisor-auto-proxy-creator-enabled: false
and to add the spring-boot-starter-aop dependency.
See [doc][1]

  [1]: https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/SpringBootStarter